# Entity reference get all related items in a view

Tags: entities, views

I'd like to have a view block on my content page that shows ALL related content. ALL in the sense of chaining - if Node A references Node B which references Node C which references Node D, then nodes B, C, and D all show up on Node A's page even though it itself is only related to Node B. How can I set this up?

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing this in a non-programmatic way is to use [views_field_view](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_field_view). With this method you will only get a set number of nesting levels - for example 4 levels: create a view of your specific node Content Type with 4 Pages, A, B, C, and D. In Page A, insert a Views Field that references Page B, in B a field to Page C, and in C a reference to page D. Pages B, C and D should have a contextual filter for a Node ID (nid). In each page, the Views Field View field should pass the Node Reference as an argument to the next Page. I hope this is clear. Let me know if it's not, and I can expand this.

EDIT: If you are looking for "infinite depth" I suggest that you look at the programmatic alternative for Views, [EntityFieldQuery()](https://www.drupal.org/node/1343708). Perhaps a recursive call to a function that does the query, while you build a global multi-depth array with the data you need, then theme it as a table.

Comment: Thanks for this idea. Though I'm really looking for non-defined depth.

Comment: See my edited suggestion

Comment: Re: my edited answer. Using a recursive function will allow you to have infinite depth, but you also run the danger of getting into an infinite loop if one of the children nodes references a node above itself.

Comment: Then don't use recursion but rather keep iterating until you no longer have references to follow. Have an array contain all node IDs found so far and only add to it if the node ID doesn't already exist. Good luck.